# 'nutc': unknown terminal type. docker

Tags: docker

I have a windows 7 box. I am trying to run Docker quickstart. It keeps dying with the following error...

```
Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Waiting for an IP...
Machine "default" was started.
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Started machines may have new IP addresses. You may need to re-run the `docker-m
achine env` command.
Regenerate TLS machine certs?  Warning: this is irreversible. (y/n): Regeneratin
g TLS certificates
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
'nutc': unknown terminal type.
Looks like something went wrong in step ´Finalize´... Press any key to continue.
```

On doing a search on the internet I can see that some people have suggested commenting out clear in start.sh which I have also tried but doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Has anyone got any ideas on how I might get past this?

thanks

Comment: I found an answer from https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-quickstart-terminal-nutc-unknown-terminal-type/5165/5: 
Add the line "export TERM=cygwin" in start.sh.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for Windows 7 Docker ToolBox:**

cd to installed folder Ex: *"C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox"* 
then, type "bash" and enter 
run "./start.sh" 
hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

It breaks on the "clear" command in the start.sh script (corresponding to the "Docker quickstart Terminal" icon)

If you comment the clear command just after STEP="Finalize"
adding a # like that

```
#clear
```

At least like taht the it will run.

Personnally my terminal has then problems with backspace key and arrows keys.